# How do I share my screen to airplay / AppleTV?

Tags: screencast, airplay

I've seen a lot of posts about streaming audio to their AppleTV / other airplay audio devices... but I want to share my screen.

Is there a way I can do this?

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  Airplay is a proprietary protocol that hasn't been fully reverse engineered.  That might even never happen.

If you are not bound to Apple, you might look into [DLNA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Living_Network_Alliance).

Comment: Ok, cool, thanks for the clarification! I'm personally not bound to apple, but my company uses airplay in meeting rooms. I personally cast my screen with chromecast at home, though. :-)

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Connect to the wifi network of the AppleTV

Download or clone from this link:
https://github.com/jamesdlow/open-airplay

Once you have downloaded the `.zip`, unzip it and enter the folder `open-airplay-master`.

The document “Dockerfile” contains the list of instructions:
From terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y default-jdk
sudo apt-get install -y maven2
```

Apparently the `maven2` library is not available on Ubuntu 16. In this case, you should install the `maven` library with the same command as above.

From terminal:

```
cd open-airplay-master/Java
ant
```

The command `ant` builds the `airplay.jar` file in the `open-airplay-master/Java/build` folder.

From terminal:

```
cd open-airplay-master/Java
java -cp "build/airplay.jar:lib/jmdns.jar" com.jameslow.AirPlay
```

You should see a searching window for few seconds.
It should find the AppleTV automatically (click OK).
Select resolution and click OK.

Now you should see your screen projected.

Comment: does this work pretty consistently? thanks for the detailed instructions?

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is a way - https://github.com/jamesdlow/open-airplay It is not really fancy, but it works:

1. Download latest release of airplay.jar (in GitHub there is "2 releases" link)
2. Download supplementary library jmdns.jar (stored in folder Java/lib)
3. Execute from folder with downloaded jars by **java -cp "airplay.jar:jmdns.jar" com.jameslow.AirPlay**

It should show list of available devices after a few seconds, then ask for resolution and finally share your screen.

Comment: does this work pretty consistently?

Comment: No longer working, too old